# Make While Statement True (Calling Method from Another Class)

Tags: java, loops

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Encryption pass = new Encryption();

        while(CODE){
            System.out.println("Please enter a password");
            String name = KeyboardReader.readLine();

            System.out.println("Encrypted Password:  " + pass.encrypt(name));
            System.out.println("Decrypted Password:  " + pass.decrypt(name));
        }
    }

    boolean isValidLength (String password) {
        if (password.length() < minLength) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go by making the statement true above? I need to make it so that if the user enters a password not long enough or not a valid password they can re enter it over and over again.  Not sure if my while loop is correct, but I have to call from my isValidLength method to make it true.  Any mistakes found would be helpful too.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you pay close attention to your indenting. Right now, your code is difficult to read because the indenting is pretty haphazard. This is an important aspect of writing readable code, and is something you should practice right from the beginning.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'll pay more attention next time.

Comment: Also, please convert tabs to spaces before posting code.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this:

```
while(true){
    //read the password
    ...
    if (isValidLength(password)){
        break;
    }
}
//proceed with encryption
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `do ... while` instead of a `while` loop. In pseudocode:

```
boolean ok;
do {
    <get user input>
    ok = <check validity of user input>
} while (!ok);
```

If you *must* use a `while` loop, just use the above logic but initialize `ok` to `false`:

```
boolean ok = false;
while (!ok) {
    <get user input>
    ok = <check validity of user input>
}
```

Also, I think the logic that you currently have in `isValidLength` is backwards. It will also have to be declared `static` if it is to be called from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few things that need attention:

- Your call to `pass.decrypt(name)` appears to pass the *plaintext* entered by the user to a function called `decrypt()`. Perhaps you wanted to pass the return value of `pass.encrypt(name)` instead?
- Your `isValidLength()` function returns `true` if the length of the string is *less than* your minimum. I think you want this the other way around.

For your `while` loop, I suggest a structure commonly called "loop-and-a-half":

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a password:");
    String name = KeyboardReader.readLine();
    if (isValidLength(name)) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Your entered password was not long enough.");
}
System.out.println("Encrypted Password:  " + pass.encrypt(name));
// ... rest of code
```

With this construct, the `break` is in the middle of the loop. The bottom half of the loop is a place to tell the user what they need to do to correct their erroneous input. After the loop ends, you can assume that the user's input has passed the `isValidLength()` check.

Comment: `isValidLength` also returns `true` if a condition is `true` and `false` if that same condition is `false`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, that's true. I suspect the redundant code is of lesser importance than the logic error at this point. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's one of those codes where you don't know where to start from.