# Loop to Re Enter

Tags: java

```
import csci130.*;

public class Driver {
public static void main(String args[]){

    Encryption pass = new Encryption();

    System.out.println("Please enter a password:");
    String name = KeyboardReader.readLine();

    while (true) {
        if (isValidLength(name)) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Your entered password was not long enough.");
    }
    System.out.println("Encrypted Password:  " + pass.encrypt(name));
    System.out.println("Decrypted Password:  " + pass.decrypt(name));
}
}
```

---

```
boolean isValidLength (String password) {
if (password.length()>minLength)    {
    return true;

}   else    {
    return false;
 }
}
```

Wondering how I could get the loop to work so I can have the user re enter the length if the length is not long enough? Right now when I compile it will say that the password is not long enough, but will not let them re type a valid password. Any suggestions?

Comment: also, the format was being difficult on the website for some reason (might be change of computer) so I apologize..

Comment: Do you know which line of your current code reads a password from the user?  You should probably add that code into the loop, no?

Comment: Well I do have a password for the user to enter. Really the "password" is a user entered string that gets "encrypted, and String is permutated, but if its not long enough, i need the user to validate until they give a string that is long enough..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make While Statement True (Calling Method from Another Class)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575109/make-while-statement-true-calling-method-from-another-class)

Answer (score 2):

You're close.

If you want to re-ask the user to enter a password if the previous attempt was invalid, I would think about moving your question and `readLine()` into the while loop.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a password:");
    String name = KeyboardReader.readLine();
    if (isValidLength(name)) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your entered password was not long enough.");
    }
}
```

I also made one other adjustment: moving your "not long enough" message into an `else` block. This structure will make more sense if you decide to add more validation checks on your input.

Answer (score 1):

Move the part where the name is read into the loop:

```
String name;
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a password:");
    name = KeyboardReader.readLine();
    if (isValidLength(name)) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Your entered password was not long enough.");
}
System.out.println("Encrypted Password:  " + pass.encrypt(name));
System.out.println("Decrypted Password:  " + pass.decrypt(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the readLine() into the loop so that the `name` variable gets a new password:

```
while (true) {
    if (isValidLength(name)) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Your entered password was not long enough.");

    System.out.println("Please enter a password:");
    name = KeyboardReader.readLine();
}
```